# Rigid body falling through conveyer belt

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, physics

I made a conveyer belt and then I tried putting a cube on top of it. The belt carries the cube like you would expect, but about half way through, the cube falls through the belt.

[Video](https://youtu.be/Mc6PhccOvi0)

[image]

Comment: You have to increase the simulation substeps. You can find this option here world -> physics -> physics steps -> substeps ([Blender Wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/File:Physics_panel.png))

Comment: The .blend links to the same place as the video. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to upload your file. (It is free and built just for this site by the community)

Comment: @cegaton Sorry! It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

That happens to me sometimes. I dont remember exactly what i did to fix it but i think the problem was caused because it had something to do with moving the origin and editing the mesh once a rigid body is added to the mesh. I think if you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and select origin to center mass it might work.